# Button click displays each row information

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, aspxgridview

When button(Select) is clicked at the beginning of the each row modal with the information(data) about the current row needs to be displayed.

Gridview is dynamical and it's populated directly from a database.
This is the code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvMyObjekats" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >

            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                   <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Button Text="Select" ID="myButton" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ObjekatsID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="ObjekatsID" runat="server" Width="118px" Height="26px" style="text-align:center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("ObjekatsID") %>'></asp:Label>


                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ObjekatsName">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="ObjekatsName" runat="server" Width="118px" Height="26px" style="text-align:center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("ObjekatNames") %>'></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="StatusID">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="StatusID" runat="server" Width="118px" Height="26px" style="text-align:center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("StatusID") %>'></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SecondObjekatID">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="SecondObjekatID" runat="server" Width="118px" Height="26px" style="text-align:center" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("SecondObjekatID") %>'></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>


        </asp:GridView>
```

I have tried many things, but I didn't have any luck :/
Can someone please help me with this task?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you want the data to be displayed? and please add the HTML code for the modal.

Comment: Along with jQuery code what you have till now

Comment: In a form of a modal.
Something like this:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals